# What's the quickest way to parse and display a `.csv` file?

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I am currently using python with matplotlib to display a 440+ k lines `.csv` but it takes `11 sec` to display only one column.
My `.csv` has always the same format. Is there a way to parse it quicker ? I choose to store all the column into lists then display it.

Here is the code I made :

```
csv_path = "C:/Users/mydata.csv"
csv_database = open(csv_path, delimiters=";")    
data_dict = csv.DictReader(csv_database, delimiter=";")

current_row = 0

number_list = []

for row in data_dict:

   current_row += 1 # Skip heading row

   if current_row == 1:
       continue

   # Here I add to a list of strings already created 
   name_list.append(row["Name"]) # Assuming the header of the column is "Name"

   # Here I add to a list of integer 
   if row['Number'] == 'NULL':
        int_list.append(0)

   elif row['Number'] != " ":

        int_list.append(int(row['Number'])) # Assuming the header is "Number"

   else:
        int_list.append(0)
```

Comment: What have you already tried? can you provide your sample code for us to comment on?

Comment: I tried and it works, but before going any further I wanted to ask if I was going in the good direction. Anyway, code added :)

Comment: @JeanRene FYI: [Fastest Python library to read a CSV file](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7463/903).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Well thank you, that's a really useful benchmark!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks ok to me.  This will work for your small scale CSVs (sub a couple of thousand rows).

When I had tp parse huge CSV Files (100k rows +) - I used the Cassava module which out performed the native modules by a long way.

Take a look at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cassava

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks but isn't Cassava for Haskell? Does it integrate well with a Python program?